# Trouble with three-way SQL join

Tags: mysql, join

I'm new to SQL joins and haven't found the right way to accomplish what I need.  I'm trying to write a job that will run once a day to collect the `id` and `email` values from the `customers` table, but only for appointments that occurred *yesterday*.

Note: I'm working with a proprietary system and don't have access to change the way data is organized in the db.  For the sake of clarity, I have excluded the non-important fields from this post.

Assume the following three table structures and data in mySQL:

table: customers

```
id | email
   1 | user@domain.com
   2 | user2@domain.com
   ...
```

table: customer_appointments

```
customer_id | appointment_id
   1 | 200
   2 | 201
   1 | 202
   2 | 203
   ...
```

table: appointments

```
id | start_date
   200 | 2018-04-02 00:09:00
   201 | 2018-04-02 00:10:00
   202 | 2018-04-03 00:09:00
   203 | 2018-04-03 00:01:00
   ...
```

What I think I need to do is:

- select all `appointments.id` that occurred yesterday from `appointments` using:

  SELECT `id` FROM `appointments` where DATE(start_date) = DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY);
- join the `appointments.id` values with `customer_appointments.customer_id`
- join the `customer_appointments.customer_id` values with `customers.id`

I've made several attempts, but my lack of knowledge on joins is really getting in the way.  :)

Any tips you can provide would be appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: Your approach looks fine so what problem are you having?

Comment: Concepts are easy.  I can't seem to nail down the correct query to make this work.

Comment: Post an attempt and it will be critiqued , hopefully in a helpful way.And google mysql join three tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things you need to watch out for 1) id in select is ambiguous you need to qualify it with the table name (or alias thereof) 2) wp_ab_customers.id.id - might be a typo but .id should only appear once 3) the date test is not bracketed properly after the = operator 4) you need to reverse the order of your joins - mysql needs to read in top down order in this case ie  wp_ab_customers>>wp_ab_customer_appointments>>wp_ab_appointments 5) Using table aliases would make this a lot easier to read.

So here's the final tidied up code

```
SELECT wp_ab_customers.id,email ,wp_ab_appointments.start_date
FROM wp_ab_customers 
INNER JOIN wp_ab_customer_appointments ON wp_ab_customer_appointments.customer_id = wp_ab_customers.id 
INNER JOIN wp_ab_appointments ON wp_ab_customer_appointments.appointment_id = wp_ab_appointments.id 
where DATE(wp_ab_appointments.start_date) = (date(now()) - interval 1 day);

+------+------------------+---------------------+
| id   | email            | start_date          |
+------+------------------+---------------------+
|    1 | user@domain.com  | 2018-04-02 00:09:00 |
|    2 | user2@domain.com | 2018-04-02 00:10:00 |
+------+------------------+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

And with table aliases

```
SELECT c.id,email ,a.start_date
FROM wp_ab_customers as c
INNER JOIN wp_ab_customer_appointments as ca ON ca.customer_id = c.id 
INNER JOIN wp_ab_appointments as a ON ca.appointment_id = a.id 
where DATE(a.start_date) = (date(now()) - interval 1 day);

+------+------------------+---------------------+
| id   | email            | start_date          |
+------+------------------+---------------------+
|    1 | user@domain.com  | 2018-04-02 00:09:00 |
|    2 | user2@domain.com | 2018-04-02 00:10:00 |
+------+------------------+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: This works and, most importantly, gives me something to learn from.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

With this one you will get the customer id, the appointment id and the email:

```
SELECT a.id ,b.appointment_id,c.email
FROM appointments a
    join customer_appointmens b on a.id=b.appointment_id
    join customers c on c.id=b.customer_id
where DATE(a.start_date) = DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to provide a solution.